# Put a cell in specific section of a Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view controller with three sections and I don't know how I can choose in which sections I want to put cells after a condition for exemple. And also to define the number of cell per section dynamically.

In my code, I have 3 sections, I know that I will have only 1 cell for the section "Present show" but for the other section it depends of the number of show

My code :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionName;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            sectionName = @"Past show";
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionName = @"Currentshow";
            break;
        default:
            sectionName = @"Futur Show";
            break;
    }
    return sectionName;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.scheduleList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    TVShow *tvc = self.scheduleList[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tvc.title;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    if ([self isTimeForAshow: tvc]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
       // NSLog(@"%@ -time for show %@, show duration %@", tvc.title, tvc.startTime, tvc.duration);
    }
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = tvc.startTime;

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check `indexPath.section` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and make your decision based on its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain three lists of schedules (e.g. `pastScheduleList`, `currentScheduleList`, `futureScheduleList`). You can then use a similar test structure as the one you use in `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. For example, for `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`:

```
NSInteger sectionCount;
switch (section)
{
    case 0:
        sectionCount = [self.pastScheduleList count];
        break;
    case 1:
        sectionCount = [self.currentScheduleList count];
        break;
    default:
        sectionCount = [self.futureScheduleList count];
        break;
}
return sectionCount;
```

For `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you will need to switch on `indexPath.section`.